# Will files that are skipped in git cherry-pick be included in a later git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I'm working on a project using Moodle 2.9.4

There is some code I would like to cherry-pick from Moodle 3

but I don't want to include some of the files updated in the commits.

Eventually the project will be upgraded to Moodle 3 using git merge

Will the excluded files will be included in the merge?

If not, what's the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways to understand your question:

> Will files that are skipped in git cherry-pick be included in a later
>   git merge?
>   **If I exclude them from the cherry-pick, will the merge still add them?**

Yes

> Will files that are skipped in git cherry-pick be included in a later
>   git merge?
>   **Will I get troubles with these files when merging if I exclude them from the cherry-pick?**

No

Git only cares about `changes` so cherry-pick is just about copying a few `changes` from a branch to another. By excluding some of the *files* in the commit you are actually excluding `changes` so you make it easier for a later merge.
If you ever merge with Moodle 3 you may get merge conflicts on the `changes` that you cherry-picked from Moodle 2 if the Moodle 3 branch brings more `changes` to these changes after you cherry-picked them.

TL;DR: The fewer changes you cherry-pick the easier it may be in the future, so that looks to me to be a good strategy to exclude the files you don't need from the cherry-picking.

(I like to keep my answers short but don't hesitate to ask for more precisions if there is something you did not understand. )